# How do I create a direct link for google play music?

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play

I understand that the direct link for apps is -> `market://apps/collection/<id & name>`

Does anyone know how to make the link directly connect to a music album or book even.

`market:// ??`
I'd even take an older format `http://market.android.com/<id & name>`

On older android devices the typical hyperlink won't open in the market, just the browser. `http://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/<id & name>`

Comment: [Linking to your products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#UriSummary) only mentions links to apps :/

Answer (score 0):

```
http://market.android.com/music
```

seems to work ok. I could not find a way to link directly with the more "updated" market:// prefix. Even some of the documentation on the market intent page