# How do I make a URL that will go to Google Play Music search on browser as well as Android App

Tags: android, url, google-play

This URL (when logged into Google Play Music) goes to the expected search results in a browser:

`https://play.google.com/music/listen#/sr/beyonce`

When this link is clicked from Chrome on Android, you get the option to open it with the Google Play Music app.  If I choose to open with that app, it does not initiate a search for `beyonce` like it does in the browser.

[The documentation here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#PerformingSearch) almost works, i.e. `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=beyonce`, but replacing `store` with `music` is a 404, and I really need the link to open the music section instead of the generic store search.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577254/how-do-i-create-a-direct-link-for-google-play-music) is similar, but I specifically want to link to a search result instead of a particular item.

Can I make one URL that will behave correctly in both circumstances?  If I can't, then I could detect Android and offer a different URL for Android users.  How do I form that URL correctly?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? It's kind of stupid that the app does open when the user clicks the link but ignores search query and then just sits there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I think this is the equivalent way of searching for music instead of apps according to the documentation: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=skillet+sick+of+it&c=music

You set c=music

Comment: This seems to go to music purchases, not the player.